# Please take your own question(s) seriously

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In general, people who answer questions on AU do their job with a certain pride. We want answers *to work*. If not, we either remove the answer or edit it until it works for *at least* the situation of OP, but if possible, for a wider range of situations.

This process works best while *still in the flow* of the question. That implies that if the first sign of life of OP comes after 4 or 5 days, the mind has moved on and it is less likely the answer is *edited* with the same creativity as what is was *written* with.

Unlike what some people seem to think, asking for feedback is not so much a matter of chasing reputation, but we simply want a *confirmed* working answer. Not only for ourselves, but mainly for the sake of the quality of the site. That is why it is discouraging and kind of frustrating to read a comment like *"thanks for the answer, I will look into it one of these days, this week, next week, who knows..."*. Even worse of course if there is no reaction *at all*.

If you know someone responds accurately to his or her questions, you feel like doing "an extra step", since you know your work will be fruitful. The other way around: if you have the experience someone neglects answers, communicates very slowly (or not) or tends to abandon his own questions, it is unlikely you will take the effort to even write a comment, although you like the question at first sight.

***In short***: if you ask a question, take the time to communicate in an accurate way. It is good for the site, for the quality of your answer and improves the chances you'll get good answers in the future. Be aware of the fact that ***this is not a personal help desk***, but we create question/answer combinations to serve a wider audience then the person who asks and answers the question.

Comment: I will read this question in 6 to 8 weeks

Comment: @Braiam perfect, I will wait for your answer :)

Comment: I'm confused...

Comment: Is "I have access to AU only on the weekend" or "only on weekdays" a legit excuse?

Comment: @JacobVlijm waiting for [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/270345) is rarely a good idea. :)

Comment: Many of these issues come from new user accounts. Is there any way in which we can encourage users at registration to follow up on their inquiries?

Comment: Sadly, those people who abandon their questions are unlikely to read Meta.

Comment: @Takkat totally true of course. One of the reasons for writing this post was to create an option to add a "please see this" comment, stripped from the annoyance of the moment, instead of writing a long story in a comment :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm --- +1, perfectly agree to you. I did  complain for something related once (http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13515/upvoting-questions-and-then-answers); unfortunately I think that this is an effect of the carelessness of the average new user of this site. We have a lot of shot an answer, get bored, forget, I don't mind if you spent half an hour of your life trying to help. It's a lot more rewarding asking and answering, for example, in the `tex` site...

Comment: Yes, agreed . . . but that's all there is to it . . . People who answer questions here probably have an idea of how to take care of their own questions . . . but most new users do not. They won't even know this meta question, or meta site exists unless they spend at least a month of active use of the site. At least that's the way i see it . . .

Comment: If there's a lot of support for this, can we discuss the site limitation that says the quickest we can get notified about post replies is every 3 hours? Every other forum allows instant notification by email. I completely agree with Jacob's point, but it's somewhat unfair to criticise question askers for letting the flow go cold, when there's a feature on the website which introduces a 3 hour response lag.

Comment: You might find this question interesting: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196219/70524 (note the dates)

Comment: @dez93_2000 there's no such thing as far as I know. You get notified of new answers/comment replies pretty much immediately. What is this 3 hour lag you speak of?

Comment: @JacobVlijm could you clarify what you mean by "if you ask a question, include the time to communicate in an accurate way."? Do you want people to add something like "I will be available to answer comments Monday to Friday, after 8pm"?

Comment: @terdon Not literally like that. What I mean is that the (quality of the) response, you give to possible answers within a reasonable amount of time, is part of the quality of a question. Asking a question, but not making clear (taking the time to explain-) if an answer works (and if not, why not), is a waste of the answerer's work. It reduces the use of a good answer for other users. Assuming of course that the answer has *some* quality. Personally, I wouldn't ask a question if I knew I am not available for the next three days.

Comment: @terdon it's tucked away: click on your avatar, then settings, and it's at the top right. Email options for forum replies are weekly, daily, or 3 hours. I don't know if this is a stack exchange limitation though?

Comment: @dez93_2000 oh _email_. I never use those, I receive my notifications on-site.

Comment: @terdon I assume one has to keep the site open for that to happen though right? Not abnormal if you're an AU lifer but less likely if you're a new poster. This has been discussed briefly on SE meta (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243059/increasing-number-of-frequency-options-for-emailing-unread-inbox-messages); if it's something that this community feels strongly about, conceptually we could petition SE to allow immediate email to the AU subforum, or site-wide?

Comment: Yes, I kind of live on SE. I have 12 SE-related pinned tabs... Sounds like a good idea site-wide though. On the other hand, 3 hours is not that long. Dunno. If you want more, keep the tab open.

Comment: As a newish AU user I do have a suggestion that might help, remind the poster of their post by email say 2 days after inline with the bounty time. Sure it shouldn't need to be that way but most of the people coming here for answers will be pretty new to ubuntu and maybe even this style of "help site". Ive been around the Stack exchange sites a while now so i think i get the jist of if, but many wont or may simply forget about their post if they happen to solve the problem only coming back weeks later with another problem.

Comment: No, browser push notifications (chrome i know for sure i guess chromium and soon others) are available as long as the browser is open, the site doesn't need to be. I guess at some point if its not already available, they will be able to run in the background even when the browser is closed. (i dont let my browser run in the background so i dont know the latter part)

Answer (score 30):

I agree absolutely here.  There's nothing that irks me more than giving an answer to a difficult question than never hearing from the OP again.  I've run across this multiple times:

[Headphones are playing a local radio station](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649990/headphones-are-playing-a-local-radio-station/649996#649996) - OP never showed his face again
[Creating a VPN without a router for gaming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725541/creating-a-vpn-without-a-router-for-gaming/725545#725545) - OP said he'd look into it, but never heard from him again
[ubuntu demo available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719312/ubuntu-demo-available/719314#719314) - The OP here said he found a solution, but didn't answer his own question to let us know what it was
[Format usb linux Western Digital external disks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713360/format-usb-linux-western-digital-external-disks/713361#713361) - Never heard from the OP again

Questions like these irk me.  There's no reason someone who is capable of asking a question shouldn't be capable of accepting an answer.  If you're just trolling us, then go somewhere else.  Go to Area 51 and suggest a Trolls.SE site.

Sorry for the rant, but I've waited 6 to 8 weeks to say all this.

Live long, and prosper ,
His Imperial Majesty, Emperor Meatloaf

Comment: Is there any option for question responders (either responding to specific question or who've responded to a threshold number of questions) to rate the question asker, in the same reciprocal way that ebay/uber/etc works? I know there's rep, but isn't it functionally meaningless for new users? What if there was a warning text [Jacob's] shown to people posting for the e.g. <5th time, coupled with a feature to tag 'bad asker' which will mean e.g. there's a 1 day delay on your post being visible? Or similar stick-like incentive?

Comment: I don't think so.  I mean, they could recode SE to place early posts in the review queue, but that's complicateder than we want.

Comment: Wow, this is my highest upvoted answer?  I didn't even answer a question...

Comment: we're upvoting you because of the strong possibility that you're simply murdering these people. The last time anyone heard from any of them was when you gave them some advice, so...

Comment: Ha.  Too bad that meta doesn't earn rep...

Comment: @Daniel Voting is different on meta, it just shows agree or disagree, so 15 people agree with your opinion and one does not. Also "complicateder" is not a word, correct usage is "more complicated", but I agree so +1

Comment: I know how voting works.  I've even been around a little on meta.  I've just never had 17 people agree with me.  And I know proper English.  I'm white, born and raised in the Heart of Dixie.  I'm an American, meaning I have freedom of speech, so I can make up words if I want to 

Comment: Now I want a trolls.se site. Kinda like the other side of the coin, what stack does absolutely not want to be.

Comment: If I suggest one in Area 51, can you follow it and spread the word?  We might be able to get it into the beta.

Comment: @Ev1l0rd A good idea, but with one major flaw! Trolls don't troll Trolls. :) It would be a very interesting read though. Before anyone comments, I know this was back from Feb.